# How to select for 1-4 carbon sugar bond in Chemical Glycosylation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, carbohydrates

I am interested in Chemical Glycosylation, specifically the production of cellulose by synthetic means. However, it is difficult to ensure that the glycosidic bond is formed between the 1 and 4 carbons.

Are there any techniques that can select for this reaction?

I am looking for good references on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

You have to protect the OH groups you don't want to react with [protecting groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protecting_group).

In this case you could install a benzylidene acetale between the 4 and 6 OH, then protect all the other OH and then do [selective reductive opening of the benzylidene](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0008621511001583) so your benzyl group will be on position 6 and you got a free OH.
That said: it's quite expensive, labor intensive and has very bad atom economy. And you might run into problems with deprotection once you got polymer structures, so that's not a feasible option for synthesis of cellulose.

I don't think it's possible to optimize a synthesis without protecting groups, so the best way would be doing it enzymatically, which could be very expensive too.